# Terraform Azure VM extension does not join VM to Azure Active Directory for Azure Virtual Desktop

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, virtual-desktop, windows-virtual-desktop

Using https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-virtual-desktop/arm-avd-with-terraform/m-p/2639806 as inspiration, I want to deploy AVD but with AAD joined VMs using terraform. I have defined a VM and extension in Terraform alongside a Azure Virtual Desktop deployment(host pool, app group, workspace) as per the article, and I have adapted the extensions based on the ARM template generated by Azure when VMs are added to the Host Pool and joined with AAD 'manually'/through the portal.

The terraform applies and the extensions run through successfully but the VMs do not join the domain.

When I look at the logs on the deployed VM one of the main errors is 'DsrCmdAzureHelper::GetTenantId: Unable to get Tenant Id, status code 400'. I get 400 status code when getting metadata from Targeting host name:169.254.169.254, url path: /metadata/identity/info?api-version=2018-02-01 and the 'identity not found' errors follow.

What is the issue here? Below is the terraform for the extensions, let me know if more is required.

```html
locals {
  registration_token = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool.registration_info[0].token
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "domain_join" {
  count                      = var.rdsh_count
  name                       = "${var.prefix}-${count.index + 1}-domainJoin"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_vm.*.id[count.index]
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
  type                       = "AADLoginForWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmext_dsc
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmext_dsc" {
  count                      = var.rdsh_count
  name                       = "${var.prefix}${count.index + 1}-avd_dsc"
  # virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_vm.*.id[count.index]
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_vm.*.id[count.index]
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Powershell"
  type                       = "DSC"
  type_handler_version       = "2.73"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<-SETTINGS
    {
      "modulesUrl": "https://wvdportalstorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/galleryartifacts/Configuration_9-30-2021.zip",
      "configurationFunction": "Configuration.ps1\\AddSessionHost",
      "properties": {
        "HostPoolName":"${azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool.name}",
        "aadJoin": true
      }
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
  {
    "properties": {
      "registrationInfoToken": "${local.registration_token}"
    }
  }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool
  ]
}
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tested it in my environment and the issue was same like below :***

[image]

As per the discussion in this ***[`Microsoft Q & A Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/489676/aad-joined-avd-sessionhost-is-not-joined-to-a-doma.html)*** , It is mentioned that a key ***`AADJPrivate`*** should be present under path ***`HKLM\Software\microsoft\RDInfraAgent`*** , ***if it is not present then the VM will add the extensions properly but fail to domain join with Azure AD***.

***So, as a solution , I changed few things in the code like :***

> - The host had ***`custom_rdp_properties`*** as    `"audiocapturemode:i:1;audiomode:i:0;"` ***instead ,added*** `"audiocapturemode:i:1;audiomode:i:0;targetisaadjoined:i:1;"`.
> - Provided `auto_upgrade_minor_version = true` in the    ***AADLoginForWindows*** extension.
> - Added another Custom script extension to add the key `AADJPRIVATE`    for the VM's.

***After Modifications ,I tried with something like below :***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  version = "2.90.0"
}

provider "azuread" {}

data "azuread_group" "aad_group" {
  display_name = "xxxx"
  security_enabled = true
}
data "azurerm_role_definition" "vm_user_login" {
  name = "Virtual Machine User Login"
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vm_user_role" {
  scope              = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.id
  role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.vm_user_login.id
  principal_id       = data.azuread_group.aad_group.id
}

data "azurerm_role_definition" "desktop_user" { 
  name = "Desktop Virtualization User"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "desktop_role" {
  scope              = azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group.desktopapp.id
  role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.desktop_user.id
  principal_id       = data.azuread_group.aad_group.id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-avd" {
  name     = "avd-test"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "avd-vnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "defaultSubnet" {
  name           = "avd-subnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "avd-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow-rdp"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = 3389
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg_association" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.defaultSubnet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}

resource "time_rotating" "avd_token" {
  rotation_days = 30
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "avd-hp" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name

  name                     = "testhostpool"
  friendly_name            = "ansupool"
  validate_environment     = true
  start_vm_on_connect      = true
  custom_rdp_properties    = "audiocapturemode:i:1;audiomode:i:0;targetisaadjoined:i:1;"
  description              = "ansu host-poool demo"
  type                     = "Pooled"
  maximum_sessions_allowed = 10
  load_balancer_type       = "DepthFirst"

  registration_info {
    expiration_date = time_rotating.avd_token.rotation_rfc3339
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group" "desktopapp" {
  name                = "ANS-Desktop"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  type          = "Desktop"
  host_pool_id  = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.avd-hp.id
  friendly_name = "ANS-application"
  description   = "ansuman applications"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace" "workspace" {
  name                = "ANS-WORKSPACE"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  friendly_name = "ANS-AVD_WRSPC"
  description   = "Work Purporse"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace_application_group_association" "workspaceremoteapp" {
  workspace_id         = azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace.workspace.id
  application_group_id = azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group.desktopapp.id
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "sessionhost_nic" {
    count=2
  name                = "nic-ansu-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.defaultSubnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "avd_sessionhost" {
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_network_interface.sessionhost_nic
  ]
  count=2
  name                = "ansuvm-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  size                = "Standard_B2MS"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "Password@1234"
  provision_vm_agent = true
  
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.sessionhost_nic.*.id[count.index]]

  identity {
    type  = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  
  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

 source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
    offer     = "Windows-10"
    sku       = "20h2-evd"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

locals {
  registration_token = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.avd-hp.registration_info[0].token
  shutdown_command     = "shutdown -r -t 10"
  exit_code_hack       = "exit 0"
  commandtorun         = "New-Item -Path HKLM:/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/RDInfraAgent/AADJPrivate"
  powershell_command   = "${local.commandtorun}; ${local.shutdown_command}; ${local.exit_code_hack}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AVDModule" {
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_sessionhost
  ]
  count = 2
  name                 = "Microsoft.PowerShell.DSC"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_sessionhost.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Powershell"
  type                 = "DSC"
  type_handler_version = "2.73"
  settings = <<-SETTINGS
    {
        "modulesUrl": "https://wvdportalstorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/galleryartifacts/Configuration_11-22-2021.zip",
        "ConfigurationFunction": "Configuration.ps1\\AddSessionHost",
        "Properties" : {
          "hostPoolName" : "${azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.avd-hp.name}",
          "aadJoin": true
        }
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
  {
    "properties": {
      "registrationInfoToken": "${local.registration_token}"
    }
  }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS

}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AADLoginForWindows" {
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_sessionhost,
        azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.AVDModule
  ]
  count = 2
  name                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_sessionhost.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
  type                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "addaadjprivate" {
    depends_on = [
      azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.AADLoginForWindows
    ]
    count = 2
  name                 = "AADJPRIVATE"
  virtual_machine_id =    azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_sessionhost.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"${local.powershell_command}\""
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Note: As per this [***`GitHub Issue`***](https://github.com/Azure/RDS-Templates/issues/666) , you have to use azurerm provider version 2.90.0.***

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is joining the domain now and becomes available for a short time but my session hosts are now stuck at upgrading and eventually fail the MonitoringAgentCheck- which is probably another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to assign a managed identity to your VM for the Azure AD Join to work

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "avd_vm" {
  count                 = var.rdsh_count
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-${count.index + 1}"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  size                  = var.vm_size
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.avd_vm_nic.*.id[count.index]}"]
  provision_vm_agent    = true
  admin_username        = var.local_admin_username
  admin_password        = var.local_admin_password

  os_disk {
    name                 = "${lower(var.prefix)}-${count.index + 1}"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
    offer     = "Windows-11"
    sku       = "win11-22h2-avd"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```