# Azure VM: AzureADJoined is "No" even after enabling the AADLoginForWindows extension

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created a VM in Azure as mentioned below

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine_hub" {
  name                = "vm-hub"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg.location
  size                = "Standard_B8ms"
  admin_username      = "xxxxx"
  admin_password      = "xxxxx"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.virtual_machine_hub_nic.id
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
    offer     = "Windows-10"
    sku       = "21h1-pro"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_network_interface.virtual_machine_hub_nic
  ]    
}
```

and enabled the AADLoginForWindows extension

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "virtual_machine_hub_ext" {
  name                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.virtual_machine_hub.id
  type                       = "AADLoginForWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.virtual_machine_hub
  ] }
```

however "**dsregcmd /status**" command shows that it is not connected with Azure AD domain like AzureADJoined is "No"

[image]

In order to register the VM in Azure AD, I don't feel that I have the appropriate permissions. If that's the case, what level of permission is required? and what am I missing?

**Note:** I have manually joined Azure AD like mentioned below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/489676/aad-joined-avd-sessionhost-is-not-joined-to-a-doma.html), it is described that `aadj private` extension also to be created for a virtual machine under path:

> `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\RDInfraAgent\AADJPrivate`

So, another Custom script extension was added to add the key `AADJPRIVATE` for the VM.

Followed this template given by @Ansuman Bal in [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743129/terraform-azure-vm-extension-does-not-join-vm-to-azure-active-directory-for-azur) for Azure AD VM join and made a few changes to achieve the expected results as per your requirements.

***vi main.tf:***

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.37.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
provider "azuread" {}

data "azuread_group" "aad_group" {
  display_name = "<ADGroup>"
  security_enabled = true
}
data "azurerm_role_definition" "vm_user_login" {
  name = "<VM User Login>"
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vm_user_role" {
  scope              = azurerm_resource_group.rg-xxx.id
  role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.vm_user_login.id
  principal_id       = data.azuread_group.aad_group.id
}

data "azurerm_role_definition" "desktop_user" { 
  name = "xxxxxx User"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "desktop_role" {
  scope              = azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group.desktopapp.id
  role_definition_id = data.azurerm_role_definition.desktop_user.id
  principal_id       = data.azuread_group.aad_group.id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "eg-RG" {
  name     = "xxxxxtest"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "xxxx-vnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "xxxxdefaultSubnet" {
  name           = "xxxxxsubnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "xxxx-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.name
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow-rdp"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = 3389
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg_association" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.xxxxdefaultSubnet.id
  network_security_group_ID = azurerm_network_security_group.<nsg>.id
}

resource "time_rotating" Gen_token" {
  rotation_days = 30
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "new-hp" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.name

  name                     = "xxxxxhostpool"
  friendly_name            = "samplepool"
  validate_environment     = true
  start_vm_on_connect      = true
  custom_rdp_properties    = "audiocapturemode:i:1;audiomode:i:0;targetisaadjoined:i:1;"
  description              = "host-poool demo"
  type                     = "Pooled"
  maximum_sessions_allowed = 10
  load_balancer_type       = "DepthFirst"
 }
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool_registration_info" "reginfo" {
  hostpool_id     = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.new-hp.id
  expiration_date = time_rotating.avd_token.rotation_rfc3339
}
  
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group" "desktopapp" {
  name                = "xxxx-Desktop"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.name
  type          = "Desktop"
  host_pool_id  = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.new-hp.id
  friendly_name = "xxxxx"
  description   = "xxxxapplications"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace" "workspace" {
  name                = "xxxxxx-WORKSPACE"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.name
  friendly_name = "xxxxxxx"
  description   = "Purporse"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace_application_group_association" "sampleworkspaceremoteapp" {
  workspace_id         = azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace.workspace.id
  application_group_id = azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group.desktopapp.id
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "xxxx_nic" {
    count=2
  name                = "xxxx-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.xxxxxdefaultSubnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "sessionhost" {
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_network_interface.sessionhost_nic
  ]
  count=2
  name                = "xxxvm-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.eg-RG.location
  size                = "Standard_B2MS"
  admin_username      = "useradmin"
  admin_password      = "<Password>"
  provision_vm_agent = true
  
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.sessionhost_nic.*.id[count.index]]

  identity {
    type  = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  
  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

 source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
    offer     = "Windows-10"
    sku       = "20h2-evd"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

locals {
  registration_token = "${azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool_registration_info.reginfo.token}"
  shutdown_command     = "shutdown -r -t 10"
  exit_code_hack       = "exit 0"
  commandtorun         = "New-Item -Path HKLM:/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/RDInfraAgent/AADJPrivate"
  powershell_command   = "${local.commandtorun}; ${local.shutdown_command}; ${local.exit_code_hack}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "xxxAVDModule" {
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.xxx_sessionhost
  ]
  count = 2
  name                 = "Microsoft.PowerShell.DSC"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_sessionhost.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Powershell"
  type                 = "DSC"
  type_handler_version = "2.73"
  settings = <<-SETTINGS
    {
        "modulesUrl": "https://wvdportalstorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/galleryartifacts/Configuration_11-22-2021.zip",
        "ConfigurationFunction": "Configuration.ps1\\AddSessionHost",
        "Properties" : {
          "hostPoolName" : "${azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.new-hp.name}",
          "aadJoin": true
        }
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
  {
    "properties": {
      "registrationInfoToken": "${azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool_registration_info.reginfo.token}"
    }
  }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS

}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AADLoginForWindows" {
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.xxxx_sessionhost,
        azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.AVDModule
  ]
  count = 2
  name                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_sessionhost.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
  type                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "xxxxaadjprivate" {
    depends_on = [
      azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.AADLoginForWindows
    ]
    count = 2
  name                 = "AADJPRIVATE"
  virtual_machine_id =    azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_sessionhost.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"${local.powershell_command}\""
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

***terraform plan:***

[image]

***terraform apply:***

[image]

***VM Joined in AD after deployment:***

[image]

*Virtual Machine Overview:*

[image]