# Azure: Join Windows VM to domain without use of user account

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to provision a Windows VM on Azure using terraform. This VM needs to join the Azure AD, however, examples I could find online all make use of an existing user account.

This code (below) is basically what every example has been showing, where an existing domain account with the permissions to join devices to the domain is used to join the VM:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "domain_join" {
  name                       = "vmext-domainjoin"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.my_vm
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                       = "JsonADDomainExtension"
  type_handler_version       = "1.3"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  tags                       = local.tags

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "Name": "domain.com",
      "OUPath": "",
      "User": "my.user@domain.com",
      "Restart": "true",
      "Options": "3"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "Password": "my_user_password"
    }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

Is there any way of doing this without relying on the use of an user account? Ideally I'd like to do this using a Managed Identity or Service Principal.

It seems unreliable to me to be using a user account in a provisioning script; I can also forsee issues with things like 2FA causing problems. Therefor I'm really hoping there's a better / more secure way of doing this.

Comment: Try using the Service Principal ID in the 'User' field and the Service Principal secret in the 'Password' field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's another VM extension named `AADLoginForWindows` (or for linux: `AADSSHLoginForLinux`). When a VM has a Managed Identity assigned it can join an AD using that extension.

I found this information in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743129/terraform-azure-vm-extension-does-not-join-vm-to-azure-active-directory-for-azur).

Relevant code is:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "domain_join" {
  name                       = "vmext-AADLoginForWindows"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_vm.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
  type                       = "AADLoginForWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
}
```